# ReactJS - Apparent code running before fetch() has finished

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

Some background knowledge for my app:

- Backend - Python, Flask. The database is currently just nested dictionaries and lists
- Frontend - Reactjs

Functions that I will refer to:

- FetchPlayers() - uses fetch() to get a array with all the players in it from the backend. It also adds the players to the state using setState().
- EditPlayer(playerid) - uses fetch() to POST request the backend to change the information on one of the players.

So currently when the user starts the page, FetchPlayers() is called to get a list of players which will be displayed. Users can also edit these players information through a menu. When the user confirms the edit (through button press), first the app calls EditPlayer(), and then in the line after it calls FetchPlayers(), to update the list of players on the webpage.

The problem is the page is not updating with the new edit. For me the view the new edit I must reload the page. This suggests that FetchPlayers() is somehow being called before EditPlayer(). Does anyone know how I could fix this?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

```
edit_player(_playerid, _newfirstname, _newlastname, _newclass) {
    fetch('http://' + Globals.BaseIP + Globals.PortForBackend + '/api/editplayer', {
        //Options for the fetch request
        method:'POST',
        headers: {
            //Header objects
            'Accept':'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-type':'application/json'
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({UserID:UserServiceLocal.UserID(), token:UserServiceLocal.token(), GameID:this.props.gameID, PlayerID:_playerid, Firstname:_newfirstname, Lastname:_newlastname, Class:_newclass}),
        mode:'cors'
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));


}
```

Code for FetchPlayers

```
FetchPlayers () {
    fetch('http://' + Globals.BaseIP + Globals.PortForBackend + '/api/fetchplayers', {
        //Options for the fetch request
        method:'POST',
        headers: {
            //Header objects
            'Accept':'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-type':'application/json'
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({UserID:UserServiceLocal.UserID(), token:UserServiceLocal.token(), GameID:this.props.gameID}),
        mode:'cors'
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => this.parse_fetch_players_response(data))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))
}


parse_fetch_players_response(data) {
    console.log(data['players']);
    this.setState({Playerlist:data['players']});
    this.ListScrollToBottom();
}
```

Code that runs when confirm edit

```
Btn_EditPlayer() {
    this.edit_player(this.state.playereditID, this.state.playereditName, 
    this.state.playereditLastname, this.state.playereditClass);
    this.FetchPlayers();
```

Render function:

```
return (
                <div className="PageFooter" onKeyPress={(event) => this.EnterKeyPress_EditPlayer(event)}>
                    <Textinput className="FirstNameTextbox" id="playereditName" label="First name" value={this.state.playereditName} onChange={this.textinput_handleChange}/>
                    <Textinput className="LastNameTextbox" id="playereditLastname" label="Last name" value={this.state.playereditLastname} onChange={this.textinput_handleChange}/>
                    <Textinput className="ClassTextbox" id="playereditClass" label="Class" value={this.state.playereditClass} onChange={this.textinput_handleChange}/>
                    <button id='editPlayerButton' className="mdc-button mdc-button--unelevated mdl-button--colored mdc-ripple-surface" onClick={() => this.Btn_EditPlayer()}>Edit Player</button>
                    <button id="cancel-edit-player-btn" className="mdc-button mdc-button--raised mdl-button--colored mdc-ripple-surface" onClick={() => this.EditPlayer_Cancel_Btn()}>Cancel</button>
                </div>
            );
```

List Element Render function:

```
return (
            <div>
                <ul className="mdc-list" id="list-container" >

                    <li role="separator" className="mdc-list-divider"></li>

                    <li className="mdc-list-item" >
                        <span className="mdc-list-item__text list_text_firstname">
                            <b>Firstname</b>
                        </span>

                        <span className="mdc-list-item__text list_text_lastname">
                            <b>Lastname</b>
                        </span>

                        <span className="mdc-list-item__text list_text_class">
                            <b>Class</b>
                        </span>

                        <span className="mdc-list-item__graphic" role="presentation">
                            <i className="material-icons list_edit_icon">edit</i>
                            <i className="material-icons list_remove_icon">delete</i>

                        </span>
                    </li>
                    <li role="separator" className="mdc-list-divider"></li>

                    <ListEntry ListItemCSS="selected-list-entry" firstname="This is above" lastname="Butter" class="Jelly" id="1" delete_self={(playerID) => this.delete_item(playerID)} edit_button_clicked={(playerID) => this.Edit_Button_Clicked(playerID)}/>
                    <ListEntry firstname="Peanut" lastname="Butter" class="Jelly" id="1" delete_self={(playerID) => this.delete_item(playerID)} edit_button_clicked={(playerID) => this.Edit_Button_Clicked(playerID)}/>




                        {playerListItems}


                    </ul>
            </div>

            );
```

Comment: Please provide [a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code. Without it will be just a guessing game to tell what could be wrong with your code.

Comment: Can you make FetchPlayers a callback to EditPlayer so FetchPlayers only runs after EditPlayers comes back? Also, can we see your code?

Comment: @trixn Ok I'll add that!

Comment: @MichaelSorensen how do I make a call back?

Comment: @Ben10 check out this example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function (to be clear this might not be the solution to your problem)

Comment: Can you include the complete code of the component `FetchPlayers()` is inside?

Comment: @trixn whoops forgot to copy the closing curly bracket

Comment: This is not enough to identify the problem. Please provide the complete code of the component that `FetchPlayers()` is in including the `render()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `this.FetchPlayers()` from `Btn_EditPlayer()` and adding it as a callback for `edit_player` like below:

```
this.edit_player(this.state.playereditID, this.state.playereditName, 
    this.state.playereditLastname, this.state.playereditClass, this.FetchPlayers);

edit_player(_playerid, _newfirstname, _newlastname, _newclass, callBack) {
    fetch('http://' + Globals.BaseIP + Globals.PortForBackend + '/api/editplayer', {
        //Options for the fetch request
        method:'POST',
        headers: {
            //Header objects
            'Accept':'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-type':'application/json'
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({UserID:UserServiceLocal.UserID(), token:UserServiceLocal.token(), GameID:this.props.gameID, PlayerID:_playerid, Firstname:_newfirstname, Lastname:_newlastname, Class:_newclass}),
        mode:'cors'
    }).then((res) => {
        // run your callback (fetchPlayers in this case) only when we know the update is done.
       callBack()
    }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
}
```

Edit (typooo)

Comment: I added this, and the interesting thing is this.FetchPlayers() is running (because of console.log) output. However it is not changing the state of the page

Comment: Are you at least getting the  updated data and not the previous data set for the players? Also, looking at your render function it looks like this component only handles one player not all of your players. Are you just trying to update that single player on the page? If you are you should be able to pass back the updated player information from your POST request tbh and skip the secondary GET request all together.

Comment: I printed out the data from the fetchplayers(), and it was the database is updating. It's just the state is not changing.

Comment: For the list I'm using a .map() function to iterate through the array of players (which is in the state) and display a `<li>` element . And yes it's for editing one of the players

Comment: During which part of the component life cycle are you generating these <li> elements? If it's not too much trouble please update your post with the entire component.

Comment: They are being generated in the render() function

Comment: Oh and by the way, I have been able implement the feature of adding and removing players, but still I cannot get it to update the list after the edits have been made

Comment: Okay, well I might be making a few assumptions here but, it looks like your footer might be it's own individual component and right now you might be updating the state of the footer when you edit and not the state of the parent component with all your <li> elements. Could that be the case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170890/discussion-between-michael-sorensen-and-ben10).

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to know without seeing the code, but usually the problem is that you are not storing the information in state or your JSX in the render return isn't using the properties of *this.state* so it doesn't know to rerender.

Comment: What does your render function look like?

Comment: This code runs when the user clicks a button confirming that they want to  submit the edits made. I have now added that code

Comment: I'm still not seeing the render function. What is the JSX? If you don't understand, then just post all of the component code.

Comment: It's really hard to parse out with little pieces here and there. One thing that I notice:

Comment: parse_fetch_players_response(data) {
    console.log(data['players']);
    this.setState({Playerlist:data['players']});
    this.ListScrollToBottom();
}

Comment: If ListScrollToBottom depends on that state data, then it needs to be in a callback of the setState. Remember that setState is asynchronous. this.setState({Playerlist:data['players']}, this.ListScrollToBottom());

Comment: Ah yes, the ListScrollToBottom() is so the webpage scrolls down to the bottom of the list. It relies of the actual list element (`<li>`) to  find out where the bottom is